# How can I transform northing and easting from UTM zone 32N to WGS84 in an .xyz file without losing the z-values In QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, elevation, aerial-photography

To keep my drone (DJI Mavic 3 Enterprise RTK) at a constant altitude in very steep terrain, the controller needs a GeoTIFF file with WGS84 coordinates of the mapping area in advance.

I tried the plugin SRTM Downloader in QGIS. Basically it works. However, the altitude given is 30 to 40 meters below the real altitude. In addition, the grid of 30x30 meters is too coarse for my application.

The district government of Northrhine-Westphalia (Germany) offers a digital height model with a 1x1 meter grid and "correct" height information as an .xyz file for download. Euch file covers 1000x1000 meters. The coordinates are in UTM zone 32N (EPSG code: 25832) and the altitude in DHHN2016 (EPSG code: 7837).

So far I've tried to transform the .xyz files in QGIS via raster -> reprojection from UTM to WGS84. This also works, but without height values ​​and ~ 90,000 coordinates less. Another attempt was to transform northing ​​and easting ​​using online calculators and to add the height values ​​using Excel and to create a new .xyz file. However, QGIS cannot read or load the new files.

How can I transform northing and easting from UTM zone 32N to WGS84 in an .xyz file without losing the z-values in QGIS?

Comment: is the dtm (.xyz) available online? is there a link?

Comment: user2856 already posted the link to the files in his answer. Alternatively, you can search for your area at https://www.geoportal.nrw/?activetab=map, mark it with a rectangle or polygon and select the dgm1 (.xyz files) for download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [GDAL -> Warp (Reproject)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterprojections.html#warp-reproject) tool in the QGIS processing toolbox to reproject your UTM XYZ raster to WGS84. This will output an XYZ file with correct X, Y, Z (lon, lat, elevation) values.

Don't forget you will be warping the output, so you will get lots of NoData values around the edges (0 by default, but you can set it to a different value, e.g. -9999 or some other unlikely elevation value).

But note... You state in your question

> *the controller needs a GeoTIFF file with WGS84 coordinates*

So it sounds to me like you don't actually need XYZ output but GeoTIFF.  So while the example below outputs an XYZ as per the question, you can just change the output type from XYZ to GeoTIFF in the warp tool to directly output a GeoTIFF instead.

Below is an example from the first XYZ DTM [listed here](https://www.opengeodata.nrw.de/produkte/geobasis/hm/dgm1_xyz/dgm1_xyz/):

Original UTM XYZ data:

[image]

[image]

Warping:

[image]

Output WGS84 XYZ data (note surrounding -9999 NoData values shown with partial transparency just to highlight them):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Many thanks for the detailed instructions.